# How disable ARC for .mm file XCode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, automatic-ref-counting, xcode5

How disable Arc for .mm file XCode 5? 
I am recording audio using speak here apple project. Speak Here project contain some .mm file.
So How to disable Arc of single .mm file in Xcode.

Comment: The answer you want can be found in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project). > It is possible to disable ARC for individual files by adding the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for those files.

Comment: I am talking about .mm (objective c plus plus ) file.

Comment: -fno-objc-arc is not working in case of .mm file

Comment: Question is not duplicate, -fno-objc-arc flag is not working in case of .mm file

Comment: You must have misspelled it or done something wrong - I just wasted 15 minutes testing it and it worked fine for me with a newly created .mm file and the compiler flag set to -fno-objc-arc in the build phase for that file.